# Problem in using javascript childNodes.length property with elem

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a treeview with drag and drop functionality. Upon completion of drag and drop I need to find the count of the child nodes of the new parent node. So for that I'm using the following 
lines

```
var childnodelength=elem.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes.length;

alert(childnodelength);
```

But I always get the same value of 4 irrespective of the no. of childs, with the above alert.
I've also tried in the following way.

```
alert(elem.getElementsByTagName("A")[0].childNodes.length);
```

Above line always gives me 1 irrespective of the no. of childs. I am not sure if I am referring correctly in both the ways.

And hence I'm unable to find the no. of child nodes.

Please could someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: What does the HTML of the treeview look like?

Comment: have you had a look at this in Firebug by doing dir(elem) and then drilling down to what you want?

Comment: Add sample HTML else helping you is impossible

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `childNodes` only looks one level down, so the value will be the same so long as you have the same number of immediate children.  Perhaps what you wanted was to count all the children all the way down the tree?

If you want all the child elements, you can use `getElementsByTagName("*")`. Note that the use of the `"*"` argument doesn't work in IE5.5, which could also pose trouble for more recent versions of IE when running in quirks mode.

Another good thing to know about `childNodes.length` is that it may return a different value in IE than other browsers because of different ways of counting text nodes . . . If you want to exclude text nodes and only count elements you can loop through the childNodes and check the value of nodeType (1 = ELEMENT_NODE, 2 = ATTRIBUTE_NODE, 3 = TEXT_NODE, etc.)  You can also use `children` instead of `childNodes` if you only want element nodes, but in IE this incorrectly counts comment nodes, and in Firefox it wasn't supported until version 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the child node is a `DIV` or `Table` that wraps up the nodes you need to count?